# Is there a cross referenced DPR / build list, or optimized build list, somewhere?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

I'm a DM who is starting to play PC's, and I don't know the many many character options out there that well. My group is full of expert power gamers and I want my PC to match up reasonably, but I don't want to spend 300 hours reading the Compendium searching up feats / powers / combos.

For example, I recently played in a friend's campaign and used this build which turned out to be awesome:
http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2606166

I found it by searching "dnd 4e defender secondary striker".

I'd like to be able to find similar great builds for leaders or controllers etc... I know that some of the main categorizations for quality builds are DPR and that the best builds change depending on what level you're at. Is there anything out there showing some of the best builds for different roles?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

**You're looking for the [Complete Collection of Character Build links](http://community.wizards.com/forum/4e-character-optimization/threads/1478896)**

It does what it says on the tin. It has links to handbooks (which make the character creation process much more simple, and sample builds that are known-decent. Of especial note are the links to [Elysean Fields](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3524576) and the [collection of character concepts](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2801316).

The fields provide:

> The Elysian fields, or Elysium, is where heroes and those virtuous enough to be judged worthy spend eternity.  This thread is a collection of builds that, through synergy of all the various components of a character, are considered by the Character Optimization community to be superior. Looking for a particular race, class, paragon path, or epic destiny?  Search (ctrl-f) for it, all the builds have that information now.

More critically, they're a recent thread, so all the latest stuff is likely to be in them.

Also useful are the character concepts, though not as useful. They provide some of the more "standard" concepts sorted by role.

Comment: I would caution that about half the guides are not really anywhere near up-to-date with content (errata changes, newer dragon mag articles, releases of post-essentials splat books) and were last updated in 2010 and 2011. You'll always need to use your own discretion when picking feats. The General links at the top of the Complete Collection like the Art of Striking will help to prioritize whats important for a role, but ultimately it comes down to what the player envisions for their PC.